# Customization of the colorbar in Python (truncate and add more colors)

Tags: python, matplotlib, customization, contour, colorbar

I am a new in Python. Could you please help me to make a proper customization of the colorbar. I've already tried several variants from the web, but they don't work in proper way. I have the following graph with colorbar:

[image: sample graph with colorbar]

Here is the code:

```
set_cmap('rainbow')
contourf(0.5*(data1+data2))
xlabel (r'across track $\rm\,[pixels]$')
ylabel (r'along track $\rm\,[pixels]$')

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('radiance', rotation=270)
title('1.6 mue (avg: 5992-6012 cm^(-1))')
# Show the major grid lines 
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
# Show the minor grid lines 
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.4)`fig=plt.figure()
```

I need to truncate my colorbar to the values from 0 to 9, i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and create a new color for each of the value.

P.S. Commands like cbar = plt.clim(0, 9) are not working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `levels=` you can tell `contourf` for which values you want a new level. In this, case choosing `levels=0,1,2,...,9` seems to achieve what you want.

Note that the colors are decided in the call to `contourf`. The function `colorbar` just tries to visualize the colors that were used.

The code below first creates some random data between 0 and 20, with an outlier valued 50. The default call to `contourf` is compared to one were `levels` is set explicitly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import numpy as np

N, M = 100, 300
x = np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, (N, M)).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
x -=  x.min()
x *= 20 / x.max()
x[-1,-1] = 50
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,4))
cont1 = ax1.contourf(x, cmap='rainbow')
plt.colorbar(cont1, ax=ax1)
cont2 = ax2.contourf(x, levels=np.arange(10), cmap='rainbow')
plt.colorbar(cont2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]